# Transformation to lower case in C++

Tags: c++, string, lowercase

```
#include<iostream>
#include<string>
#include<cstring>
#include<cstdio>
#include<cstdlib>
#include <string>   
#include <algorithm>

using namespace std;

string A,B;

int main()
{
    int t,l,i;
    scanf("%d",&t);
    while(t--)
    {
        std::string str;
        std::getline(cin, str);
        std::transform(str.begin(), str.end(), str.begin(), ::tolower);
        cout<<str;
        /*for(i=0;i<s.length();i++)
        {
            s[i]=toupper(s[i]);
        }*/
    }

    return 0;
}
```

i wrote this code to convert to lower case but when run on ideone with input

```
1
hola please!!!
```

it shows output no can u tell or correct it morever this will help me learn the use of std:lowercase function taking getline cin as input rather than considering it as array

Comment: Text mutation is _HARD_.  Use [a library](http://site.icu-project.org/)

Comment: Are you sure the problem isn't simply that you are missing an `endl`?

Comment: 1. Put as input an uppercase variable 2. Do not mix scanf with cout, use cin instead of scanf 3. Put `std::cout << flush;` to be sure your output is flushed

Comment: @MatsPetersson: The problem is `fscanf` + `getline`

Comment: i making it for submission somewhere library wont work there:)

Comment: cinn>>t is not working also

Comment: [Works fine on ideone](http://ideone.com/Aknl3N)

Comment: u all using c+11 use c++4.7.2 :)

Comment: see this link http://ideone.com/v0mEC6

Comment: @Rapptz: not if the first line is a 1 it doesn't

Comment: ok i did this 2
Hello World!
why is t=1 not working

Comment: sorted out thanks u all \r worked

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is definitely with the way you are reading in. scanf("%d",&t); doesn't consume the return character, so it is still there on the getline, which will get an empty sting. Change it to scanf("%d\r",&t).

Comment: `"%d\r"` won't match the newline I don't think.  Don't C text streams normalize the newlines to `\n`?

Answer (score 3):

If you simplify the code, the problem can be reduced to:

```
int main() {
    int t;
    scanf("%d",&t);
    std::string str;
    std::getline(cin, str);
    std::cout<<str;
}
```

This is because scanf reads from the input until it reaches a character that doesn't match, and it leaves that character in the input buffer.  You input is "`1\nhola please!\n\0`", so `scanf` reads the `1`, and leaves the rest: "`\nhola please!\n\0`".  Then, you tell it to read until the next `\n` is found, which is immediately, so it returns an empty string.

The solution is: after using `std::cin >>` or `scanf` or whatever, if the next thing you want to do is read the rest of the line, you want to ignore that leading newline character.  The C++ way to do this is `std::cin.ignore(0xFFFFFFFF,'\n');`, which will ignore the rest of the line.  Alternatively, use `scanf("%d\n" &t);` to get the scanf to read in the newline character.

Related, you never check the validity of any of your input:

```
int main() {
    int num_lines=0; //variables on different lines and initialized
    std::cin >> num_lines
    if (!std::cin) 
        return 1;
    std::string str;
    for(int j=0; j<num_lines && std::getline(sd::cin, str); ++j) {
         std::transform(str.begin(), str.end(), str.begin(), ::tolower);
         std::cout << str;
    } 
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Or simply use < boost/algorithm/string.hpp >  header and function boost::to_lower().

```
int t = 0;
scanf("%d",&t);
std::cin.ignore();
while(t--) {
  std::string str;
  std::getline(cin, str);
  boost::to_lower(str);
  std::cout << str << std::endl;
}
```